# При изменении параметра skip в запросе к API Яндекс карт меняется кол-во найденных позиций в ответе (found)

Tags: yandex-maps-api

При изменении параметра skip в запросе к API Яндекс карт меняется кол-во найденных позиций в ответе (found).

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"properties": {
    "ResponseMetaData": {
        "SearchResponse": {
            "found": 102,
            "display": "multiple"
        },
        "SearchRequest": {
            "request": "IT компании Ростова-на-Дону",
            "skip": 0,
            "results": 50,
            "boundedBy": [
                [
```

Меняем skip, меняется found:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"properties": {
    "ResponseMetaData": {
        "SearchResponse": {
            "found": 185,
            "display": "multiple"
        },
        "SearchRequest": {
            "request": "IT компании Ростова-на-Дону",
            "skip": 50,
            "results": 50,
            "boundedBy": [
                [
```

Разве found не должен показывать общее кол-во найденных позиций?

Answer (score 0):

При значительном числе объектов в ответе found не должен показывать точных значений, он сохраняется для понимания объёма выдачи и того, что вы задали неточный запрос, раз ответов больше, чем несколько.

Сервис создан не для выгрузки каталога объектов, а для поиска конкретного по адресу или координатам и категории. После первых единиц-десятков строк релевантность выдачи падает. Что в них попадает — нет смысла принимать во внимание, как и количество этих строк.